# c++ windows pass the result from GetLogicalDrives to GetVolumeInformation

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Helo,

Im using GetLogicalDrives to get all the drives, and i want to use this further to detect drive type and then check the status of a specific drive, using GetVolumeInformation. However im not able to use the result from GetLogicalDrives(DWORD ) in GetVolumeInformation and GetDriveTypes as they excpects LPCWSTR. How can i convert the result from GetLogicalDrives and pass it over to GetVolumeInformation and GetDriveTypes?

```
        TCHAR myDrives[] = L" A";
        DWORD myDrivesBitMask = GetLogicalDrives();
        WCHAR szTest[10];



      if (myDrivesBitMask == 0)
wprintf(L"GetLogicalDrives() failed with error code: %d\n", GetLastError());
        else {
            wprintf(L"This machine has the following logical drives:\n");
            while (myDrivesBitMask) {
                // Use the bitwise AND with 1 to identify 
                // whether there is a drive present or not. 
                if (myDrivesBitMask & 1) {
                    // Printing out the available drives                
                    wprintf(L"drive %s\n", myDrives);
                }
                // increment counter for the next available drive.   
                myDrives[1]++;
                // shift the bitmask binary right    
                myDrivesBitMask >>= 1;
            }
            wprintf(L"\n");
        }
UINT test;
for (i = 0; i<12; i++)
    {
        test = GetDriveType(myDrives[i]);
        switch (test)
        {
        case 0: printf("Drive %S is type %d - Cannot be determined.\n", myDrives[i], test);
            break;
        case 1: printf("Drive %S is type %d - Invalid root path/Not available.\n", myDrives[i], test);
            break;
        case 2: printf("Drive %S is type %d - Removable.\n", myDrives[i], test);
            break;
        case 3: printf("Drive %S is type %d - Fixed.\n", myDrives[i], test);
            break;
        case 4: printf("Drive %S is type %d - Network.\n", myDrives[i], test);
            break;
        case 5: printf("Drive %S is type %d - CD-ROM.\n", myDrives[i], test);

            break;
        case 6: printf("Drive %S is type %d - RAMDISK.\n", myDrives[i], test);
            break;
        default: "Unknown value!\n";
        }
    }



    (GetVolumeInformation(myDrives, volumeName, ARRAYSIZE(volumeName), &serialNumber, &maxComponentLen, &fileSystemFlags, fileSystemName, ARRAYSIZE(fileSystemName)))
            {
                _tprintf(_T("There is a CD/DVD in the CD/DVD rom"));
                _tprintf(_T("Volume Name: %s\n"), volumeName);
                _tprintf(_T("Serial Number: %lu\n"), serialNumber);
                _tprintf(_T("File System Name: %s\n"), fileSystemName);
                _tprintf(_T("Max Component Length: %lu\n"), maxComponentLen);

            }
            else
                _tprintf(_T("There is NO CD/DVD in the CD/DVD rom"));
```

Comment: Use [`GetLogicalDriveStrings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364975(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of `GetLogicalDrives`.

Comment: Or, simply map drive number `0` to `A:\`, and so on (alphabetically).

Comment: For modern Windows things can be simplified considerably by just using Unicode (the `wchar_t` type) throughout, instead of the Windows 9x compatibility macros like `TCHAR`.  After all, your toolchain can probably not even produce a Windows 9x executable. So that stuff is all for nothing, except complicating things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you need drive letters to call `GetDriveType()` and `GetVolumeInformation()`, it would be easier to use `GetLogicalDriveStrings()` instead of `GetLogicalDrives()`, eg:

```
WCHAR myDrives[105];
WCHAR volumeName[MAX_PATH];
WCHAR fileSystemName[MAX_PATH];
DWORD serialNumber, maxComponentLen, fileSystemFlags;
UINT driveType;

if (!GetLogicalDriveStringsW(ARRAYSIZE(myDrives)-1, myDrives))
{
    wprintf(L"GetLogicalDrives() failed with error code: %lu\n", GetLastError());
}
else
{
    wprintf(L"This machine has the following logical drives:\n");

    for (LPWSTR drive = myDrives; *drive != 0; drive += 4)
    {
        driveType = GetDriveTypeW(drive);
        wprintf(L"Drive %s is type %d - ", drive, driveType);

        switch (driveType)
        {
            case DRIVE_UNKNOWN:
                wprintf(L"Cannot be determined!");
                break;
            case DRIVE_NO_ROOT_DIR:
                wprintf(L"Invalid root path/Not available.");
                break;
            case DRIVE_REMOVABLE:
                wprintf(L"Removable.");
                break;
            case DRIVE_FIXED:
                wprintf(L"Fixed.");
                break;
            case DRIVE_REMOTE:
                wprintf(L"Network.");
                break;
            case DRIVE_CDROM:
                 wprintf(L"CD-ROM.");
                 break;
            case DRIVE_RAMDISK:
                wprintf(L"RAMDISK.");
                break;
            default:
                wprintf(L"Unknown value!");
        }
        wprintf(L"\n");

        if (driveType == DRIVE_CDROM)
        {
            if (GetVolumeInformationW(drive, volumeName, ARRAYSIZE(volumeName), &serialNumber, &maxComponentLen, &fileSystemFlags, fileSystemName, ARRAYSIZE(fileSystemName)))
            {
                wprintf(L"  There is a CD/DVD in the drive:\n");
                wprintf(L"  Volume Name: %s\n", volumeName);
                wprintf(L"  Serial Number: %08X\n", serialNumber);
                wprintf(L"  File System Name: %s\n", fileSystemName);
                wprintf(L"  Max Component Length: %lu\n", maxComponentLen);
            }
            else
            {
                wprintf(L"  There is NO CD/DVD in the drive");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate that you took time to make this example. This simplifies the code.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a wrapper function for GetLogicalDrives() to get an easier to handle vector of drive paths:

```
std::vector< std::wstring > GetLogicalDrivePathes()
{
    std::vector< std::wstring > result;

    DWORD mask = GetLogicalDrives();
    for( wchar_t drive = 'A'; drive <= 'Z'; ++drive )
    {
        if( mask & 1 )
        {
            std::wstring rootPath;
            rootPath += drive;
            rootPath += L":\\";
            result.push_back( rootPath );
        }
        mask >>= 1;
    }

    return result;
}
```

It could be used like this:

```
for( auto& path : GetLogicalDrivePathes() )
{   
    std::wstring test = GetDriveType( path.data() );
    std::wcout << test << L'\n';
}
```

Comment: `GetLogicalDriveStrings()` would greatly simplify `GetLogicalDrivePathes()`.

Comment: I hate double-zero-terminated strings and I wanted to stick with the function used by the OP to show how it could be made working. If you like you could post an answer showing how to use GetLogicalDriveStrings() as an alternative.

Comment: Thank you this example really helped.

Comment: @zett42: *"I hate double-zero-terminated strings"* - That's an unfortunate way to interpret the data type. It really is a list of strings, terminated by an empty string. No need to invent a special semantic class to describe the list terminator.

Comment: True, but I'm still trying to avoid these APIs if possible. It isn't so hard to work with them but I often see fellow developers doing it wrong so it seems like a hard to grasp concept.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Drive strings this does the trick, I hate double NULL term strings too.
cant even look at them in the debugger or I dont know how...

This function takes that double NULL terminated string and splits it up into a CStringArray feel free to use what you like instead. It just works.

```
size_t ExtractNullTermStringsFromBuffer(CStringArray &dest, const WCHAR* SourceBuffer, const size_t BufLen)
{
    if (SourceBuffer[0] == '\0')
        return 0;
    WCHAR* strtok = new WCHAR[BufLen];
    size_t tokPos = 0;
    for (size_t curPos = 0; curPos < BufLen; ) {
        if (SourceBuffer[curPos] == '\0') { // first null byte
            strtok[tokPos] = '\0';
            tokPos = 0; // set to start new string
            dest.Add(strtok); //add it
            curPos++; // increment pos
            if (SourceBuffer[curPos] == '\0') { // check for the end
                curPos = BufLen; // break the loop
            }
        } else {
            strtok[tokPos] = SourceBuffer[curPos]; // otherwise continue
            curPos++;
            tokPos++;
        }
    }
    delete strtok;
    return dest.GetCount();
}
```

the GetLogicalDriveStrings section is here then calls the above function

```
DWORD dwSize = MAX_PATH;
    WCHAR szLogicalDrives[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    DWORD dwResult = GetLogicalDriveStrings(dwSize, szLogicalDrives);
    CStringArray dest;
    size_t szSize = ExtractNullTermStringsFromBuffer(dest, szLogicalDrives, MAX_PATH);
    for (size_t curPos = 0; curPos < szSize; curPos++) {
        //      dest[curPos]; do something with it here
    }
```